# how to discard only html tags and extracting the associated text in python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using lxml to extract the text associated with the html tags but it also treats everything in <> brackets as tag and discards it. IS there any way to retain everything other than standard html tags in the text?

```
from lxml import html
data="<EXPE>(i)<i>you</i>"
print(html.fragment_fromstring(data).text_content())
```

This gives the output

```
'(i)you'
```

But the desired output would be 
`<Expe>(i)you`

I tried the same with Beautiful soup as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)
print(text)
```

This also discards

> `'<Expe>'`

in its output. I have numerous text inside <> which are not html tags. so is there any way not to omit them?

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing can process XML or HTML tags when you don't want to necessarily build a complete document model, but just do text extraction or manipulation here and there.

Pyparsing includes a `makeHTMLTags` method to define tag-matching expressions, and `anyOpenTag` and `anyCloseTag` expressions that will match any XML or HTML tags.

A simple tag-stripper can be written with:

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> anyHtml = pp.anyOpenTag | pp.anyCloseTag
>>> anyHtml.suppress().transformString(data)
```

The `suppress()` method takes an matching text and suppresses it from the parsed output, and `transformString` processes the full input applying each parse expression.

Passing it your sample string gives the same output as BS `text()` method:

```
>>> anyHtml.suppress().transformString(data)
'(i)you'
```

But you can modify this stripper to skip over any tags you want to keep, by first checking for and negating them with '~' (short-cut operator for `pp.NotAny`). Define a parse expression that describes all the tags that you *don't* want stripped.

```
>>> keepers = pp.MatchFirst(pp.makeHTMLTags(keeper)[0] for keeper in "EXPE SAVE OTHER".split())
```

Then use this as a negative check to avoid matching your want-to-keep tags:

```
>>> (~keepers + anyHtml).suppress().transformString(data)
'<EXPE>(i)you'
```